# What is the best approach to store 10 MB JSON and perform CRUD in SFDC?

Tags: json, crud

I have a business case to design a solution for a web based excel like (UI, formulae, etc..) system.

I researched and finalized to go with JQuery.Sheet.

However, there is no recommendation laid about persistence layer with JQuerySheet control, but I need to implement an efficient CRUD operations on the DML.

Because, I need to treat every user copy as a transactional data (*data + metadata [imagine conditional formatting, formulae, etc.,]*), I would require to have some JSONPath / JSONQuery like ability also to do CRUD on cell level.

Also, my average .json data is around 10 MB, and for say 2000+ online users will not make sense to load as file.

What would be the BEST approach in designing such a solution?